# Does the halting problem belong to NP class of problems?

Tags: computability, np-hard, np, decision-problem, halting-problem

On the one hand it does not belong to NP problems because it simply is not solvable and is undecidable and on the other hand it is an NP problem because there are claims that it is NP-hard and therefore can be reduced to NP and is an NP problem.

My question, does the halting problem belong to NP?

Comment: "it is NP-hard and therefore can be reduced to NP": what ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry, I have clearly been reading wrong information. I have a feeling that it is not NP, not NP-complete and may be NP-hard (not sure how to justify). But I do not know if saying it is NP-hard means that it belongs to NP and is therefore an NP problem. I have already mentioned why it may not be NP. Why is there a lot of opinion on just whether it is an NP problem or not I do not know

Comment: As it is undecidable, it belongs to none of these classes.

Comment: So why do you think disputes still exist? That is, why does np-hard come into the equation? Or are NP hard problems simply referring to problems not solvable, including undecidable problems?

Comment: "NP-hard" doesn't mean it's in NP. NP-hard problems that are in NP are called NP-complete.

Comment: NP-hard problems are problems that would allow you to solve problems in NP, if you could only solve the NP-hard problem. Which you can't (unless P = NP, and even then there's no guarantee, and even if you can it is likely too hard).

Comment: `why do you think disputes still exist?` There is limited insight into impossibilities.

Answer (score 1):

"NP" means: We could solve this problem in polynomial when the answer is "Yes" and we are given a hint how to solve it. Every problem in NP can be solved (in a very very very long time) by trying all possible hints. But that's not the case here. It is undecidable. No hint would allow you to prove that the answer is "Yes".

On the other hand, it is quite obviously NP-hard. Given a different problem that is in NP, for example the "travelling salesman" problem, I can write a program that systematically generates all possible hints until it finds one that allows to solve the TSP instance. If that program halts, then the answer to the NP problem is "Yes". If it doesn't halt, then the answer to the NP problem is "No". So deciding that the program halts allows us to find the solution to the NP problem. Any problem in NP can be reduced to the question whether my "hint-guesser" halts or not.

Comment: `No hint would allow you to prove that the answer is "Yes".` - if the answer is "Yes", you don't even need a hint: just simulate the program (of course, it may take super-polynomial time). The major problem is the "No" part.

Comment: I meant "given a different problem in NP, for example TSP". Changing the answer.